# Reading Android Contacts in Flex?

Tags: android, apache-flex, adobe, contacts

Android is storing his contacts here:

data/data/com.android.providers.contacts/databases/contacts.db

Anyone have code to access the Android Contacts.db with Adobe Flex?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. You may not have "rights" to read this file directly from Flex/AIR
2. You need to enable rights access into your air app descriptor
3. You should create / use existing ANE (native extension) for reading contacts list

   - one example is here https://github.com/freshplanet/ContactEditor
   - About ANE http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html